# Pass named parameter to a method

Tags: java, arguments, syntax-error, named-parameters

Code:

```
class AllTheColorsOfTheRainbow {
    private int hue = 0;
    
    int anIntegerRepresentingColors;    
    
    void changeTheHueOfTheColor(int newHue) {
        this.hue = newHue;
    }

    public int getHue(){
        return this.hue;
    }
}

public class Ex11 {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        AllTheColorsOfTheRainbow a = new AllTheColorsOfTheRainbow();
        a.changeTheHueOfTheColor(newHue = 1);
        System.out.println(a.getHue());
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
 javac Ex11.java 
Ex11.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        a.changeTheHueOfTheColor(newHue = 1);
                                 ^
  symbol:   variable newHue
  location: class Ex11
1 error
```

What does this mean, and how can I correct it?

Comment: Java does not support "named arguments". If you want to call the method with the value `1`, just write `method(1)`, without the `newHue = `.

Comment: And that’s not a stack trace. It’s a compiler error. A stack Trace is what you get at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java does not have named arguments, just positional arguments. You need to pass it without the parameter's name:

```java
a.changeTheHueOfTheColor(1);
// Here -----------------^
```